# Convert ChainIndexTxOut to TxOutTx

Tags: smart-contract, plutus-playground, types

I have this function that is expecting type `TxOutTx`, but it receives `ChainIndexTxOut`. I'm trying to convert to the type required but encountering issues

```
getTradeDatum o = case txOutDatum (txOutTxOut o) of
    Just h -> do
        let [(_,datum)] = P.filter (\(h',_) -> h == h') (Map.toList (txData (txOutTxTx o)))
        let parsedDatum = PlutusTx.fromBuiltinData (getDatum datum) :: Maybe TradeDatum
        case parsedDatum of
            Just b -> b
            _ -> traceError "expected datum"
    _ -> traceError "expected datum"
```

I get the error:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `TxOutTx'
                  with actual type `ChainIndexTxOut'
    * In the first argument of `txOutTxOut', namely `o'
      In the first argument of `txOutDatum', namely `(txOutTxOut o)'
      In the expression: txOutDatum (txOutTxOut o)
    |
586 | getTradeDatum o = case txOutDatum (txOutTxOut o) of
    |
```

I've tried the following solution, changing the single line below, because `_ciTxOutValue` has worked for me before:

```
getTradeDatum o = case _ciTxOutDatum o of
```

But then I get this error:

```
 error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Either DatumHash Datum'
                  with actual type `Maybe DatumHash'
    * In the pattern: Just h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the last error tells you that you don't have a `Maybe` but an `Either` type. You're trying to pattern match against a `Maybe` instead of `Either` at this point in your code:

```
case txOutDatum (txOutTxOut o) of
   (Left _)  -> ...
   (Right _) -> ...
```

My guess is you actually want to do something like this:

```
getMyDatum :: ChainIndexTxOut -> MyDatum
getMyDatum o = case _ciTxOutDatum o of
    Left _ -> traceError "Unexpected Datumhash"
    Right (Datum d) -> do
        let parsedDatum = PlutusTx.fromBuiltinData d :: Maybe MyDatum
        case parsedDatum of
            Just s -> s
            _ -> traceError "Unknown datum type"
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate the help, that solved it :)

Comment: No prob, glad I could help. Would appreciate if you can mark my response as answer with the checkmark icon :).